# How can I go head in a props that will be rendered by a <p> tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a `<p>`tag that has as chidren a react prop.
My problem is that I'd like to go head in this prop, so I've tried `<br>` but the prop has rendered it as text, like this:
`Hi everybody <br> Hello world!`

If someone could help me I'd be very thankful.

EDIT:
The example:
example.js

```js
import React from 'react'; 

export default class Example extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <TextComponent content="Hi everybody <br /> Hello world!" /> 
        )
    }
}
```

TextComponent.js

```js
import React from 'react'; 

export default class TextComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const content = this.props.content; 
        return(
            <p>{content}</p> 
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: @romants my fault, I've forgotten it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing it as string now. Pass it as jsx and it will be fine:

```
<TextComponent content={<React.Fragment>Hi everybody <br /> Hello world!</React.Fragment>} />
```